# Keras Custom Metrics Accuracy for neighbour classes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to add a custom metric into the Keras model. Basically the custom metric considers a right prediction not only if the class predicted is the same as the true one but also when the class predicted is a neighbor of the true class. However with the code I wrote it gives me this error:

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Below is the code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import load_model

input_shape = (32, 32, 3)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='softmax'))

def one_off_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return 1 if y_pred == y_true or y_pred == y_true + 1 or y_pred == y_true - 1 else 0

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy', one_off_accuracy])

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/training',
                                                target_size=(32, 32),
                                                batch_size=1024,
                                                class_mode='categorical')


test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/test',
                                            #target_size=(224, 224),
                                            target_size=(32, 32),
                                            #batch_size=256,
                                            batch_size=1024,
                                            class_mode='categorical')

model.fit_generator(training_set,
                        steps_per_epoch= (20985/1024), 
                        epochs=25,
                        validation_data=test_set,
                        validation_steps= (5248/1024))

import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
test_image = image.load_img('dataset/1398.10693712846_42bd993ea5_o.jpg', target_size = (32, 32))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
training_set.class_indices
result = model.predict_classes(test_image)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning an integer, try to return a keras variable. I think that what keras expects :

```
import keras.backend as K

return K.variable(value=you_accuaracy)
```